# Using FFMPEG on multiple files

Tags: ffmpeg

if I want to use

`$ffmpeg -i video.avi -vf subtitles=subtitle.srt out.avi`

and I have one group of .avi files numbered ?? to ??, 
and another group of .srt files sharing the same titles

–– something that looks like:

`$ [AnimeRG] Naruto Shippuden - 072 [720p] [x265] [pseudo].ass
[AnimeRG] Naruto Shippuden - 072 [720p] [x265] [pseudo].mkv
[AnimeRG] Naruto Shippuden - 073 [720p] [x265] [pseudo].ass
[AnimeRG] Naruto Shippuden - 073 [720p] [x265] [pseudo].mkv ...`

and continues ad infinitum ––

what do I do to using the "for;do;done" formula?

below is a solution some else found for a similar problem; however it contains syntax my system doesn't recognize.

`$for %%a in ("*.mkv") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -vf subtitles=%%a.ass "%%~na.mp4"
pause`

my solution should look something like this:

`$for a in *.mkv;do ffmpeg -i "$a" -vf subtitles="$a.ass" "EmbeddedTest/${a%.mkv}.mp4";done`

Answer (score 1):

`$a.ass` will, for example, result in `[AnimeRG] Naruto Shippuden - 072 [720p] [x265] [pseudo].mkv.ass` so use `${a%.mkv}.ass` instead:

```
for a in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$a" -vf subtitles="${a%.mkv}.ass" "EmbeddedTest/${a%.mkv}.mp4"; done
```

[More info on parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073).

Comment: Gives a ––[Parsed_subtitles_0 @ 0x7fbb31705a60] No filename provided!
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fbb3150c2c0] Error initializing filter 'subtitles' with args ''
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libvorbis @ 0x7fbb32818400] 39 frames left in the queue on closing––

Comment: @croakouttatune Works for me. You can use `echo` to test what is being output and compare that to your files names: `for a in *.mkv; do echo "$a" && echo "${a%.mkv}.ass" && echo "${a%.mkv}.mp4"; done`